# Application of Inclusion-Exclusion Principle to determine number of ways to choose yogurt containers

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

A grocery shop sells $4$ different brands of yogurt. They have $12$ containers in stock, $3$ of each brand. In how many ways can one buy $6$ containers of yogurt? (Containers of the same brand are indistinguishable from each other.)

I know I am supposed to use the inclusion-exclusion principle here. Thanks to @JMoravitz, I see that this question is essentially asking me to solve the system
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=6 \\ 
0\leq x_i \leq 3\\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: $\binom{12}{6}$ counts each of the $12$ containers as distinguishable from one another.  Your problem makes it clear that containers of the same brand are indistinguishable from one another.

Comment: Your problem can be rephrased as trying to find the number of integer solutions to the system $\begin{cases}x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=6\\0\leq x_i\leq 3~~\forall i\end{cases}$.  This can be found by inclusion-exclusion based on which if any of the upperbound conditions you violated and stars-and-bars.  Alternatively, this can be found by generating functions looking at the coefficient of $x^6$ in the expansion of $(1+x+x^2+x^3)^4$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let
$$S=\{\text{all the weak compositions of }6\}$$
$$A_1=\{\text{all the weak compositions of }6 \text{ that have some }x_i=6\}$$
$$A_2=\{\text{all the weak compositions of }6 \text{ that have some }x_i=5\}$$
$$A_3=\{\text{all the weak compositions of }6 \text{ that have some }x_i=4\}$$
Then we can use the inclusion-exclusion principle such that
$$|S-(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3)|=\binom{9}{3}-\binom{4}{1,3}-\binom{4}{1,1,2}-(\binom{4}{1,1,2}+\binom{4}{1,1,2})$$
$$=44$$

Answer (score 0):

Even simpler would be to avoid four properties: $x_i \ge 4$.  Because $6<2\cdot 4$, at most one property can fail at the same time, and inclusion-exclusion yields
$$\binom{6+4-1}{4-1}-\binom{4}{1}\binom{2+4-1}{4-1}
=\binom{9}{3}-4\binom{5}{3}
=84-4\cdot 10 = 44$$